# Sum of squared dot products of a unit vector with columns of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Say we have an orthogonal matrix $\ U=[u_1 \ u_2 \ \cdots \ u_n]$, where $u_i, \ i={1,\ldots,n}$, is the ith columnn of $U$. If I took the dot product of a unit vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with each of the columns of $ \ U$, squared each of them, and summed it all up, would the result of $\sum_{i=1}^n(x^Tu_i)^2?$ be 1? In other words, is the vector with components $x^Tu_i, \ i={1,\ldots,n}$, a unit vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), $U$, we have
$$
\color{#C00}{UU^T}=I
$$
The sum of squares of the dot product of a unit vector, $v$, with the rows of $U$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\|vU\|^2
&=vU(vU)^T\\
&=v\color{#C00}{UU^T}v^T\\
&=vv^T\\
&=\|v\|^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal matrix represent a change of basis between orthonormal basis. Then if $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is orthogonal and $x\in\Bbb R^n$ then what you are describing is just $(Ax|Ax)$.

And because orthogonal matrices preserves inner products then

$$(Ax|Ax)=(x|x)=\|x\|^2$$

If $\|x\|^2=1$ it imply that $x$ is an unit vector, and viceversa.

Comment: What is the ( | ) notation you are using?

Comment: $(|)$ denotes the inner product on $ \mathbb R^n$